# Can JavaScript post messages to Flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I'm wondering if JavaScript can post JSON messages to Flash? and if so can you please provide an example or a link to one?

Comment: Possible duplication of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096188/pass-json-to-a-flash-movie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ExternalInterface class to add callback methods that Javascript can call.

for example:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("callbackName", doMyCallback);

function doMyCallback(someParam:Strimg):void {
    // use the AS3CoreLib JSON decoder like mentioned by @ludesign to decode the JSON string.
}
```

Then in your javascript, you can call the callbackName method on the flash object.

[AS3CoreLib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)
[ExternalInterface](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that you can use FlashVars for this. Been a long time since I have done it so I wouldnt be able to provide code but a quick google found a couple of links:

[http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.htm)

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/index.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: flashvars are only useful for initial loading, if you want to work with the flash player via js you have to use ExternalInterface http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html :)